# .NET SQL Query Authentication Behind Firewall

Tags: mysql, .net, c#-4.0, authentication

Our .NET desktop application currently connects to our MySQL database to authenticate the user once the software is started. 
This is a simple approach that is sufficient for us. 
The problem is that some users cannot perform the SQL query because they are behind a firewall and the SQL port is blocked. This typically happens in universities or workplace networks. We can overcome this by having the client's network administrator open the relevant port, however this is inconvenient and we would like to have a solution which would always work.

1. Is there a way to configure the MySQL server so the client can always connect?
2. If not, what would be a very simple way to authenticate users without implementing a complex client/server design?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the correct way to do this is by adding a RESTful data access layer such as [PHP REST SQL](http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/download.html).